# A result on the convergence of the vanishing viscosity approximation to the viscosity solution of an IVP for Hamilton-Jacobi equation

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

In [[CL84]](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1984-43-167/S0025-5718-1984-0744921-8/S0025-5718-1984-0744921-8.pdf), Crandall and Lions considered an initial value problem for an Hamilton-Jacobi equation and proved [[CL84, Theorem 5.1]](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1984-43-167/S0025-5718-1984-0744921-8/S0025-5718-1984-0744921-8.pdf) a result on the convergence of the vanishing viscosity approximation to the (unique) viscosity solution of the problem.

---

**Q1:** Where can I find a more recent exposition of this result (possibly with an improved proof)?

**Q2:** Are there sharper/significantly more general results of this kind?

Answer (score 1):

More generally, viscosity solutions are stable with respect to limits. The presentation of the following result, which has more general forms, is borrowed from [[Tou13]](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9781461442851).

> **Theorem:** Let $\mathcal{O}$ be open and $u_\epsilon$ be an LSC supersolution of $$F_\epsilon(\cdot,u_\epsilon(\cdot),Du_\epsilon(\cdot),D^2u_\epsilon(\cdot))=0 \text{ on }\mathcal{O}$$ where $(F_\epsilon)_{\epsilon > 0}$ are <s>elliptic and</s> continuous operators. Suppose $(\epsilon,x)\mapsto u_\epsilon(x)$ and $(\epsilon,z)\mapsto F_\epsilon(z)$ are locally bounded and let $$
> \underline{u}(x)=\liminf_{(\epsilon,x^{\prime})\rightarrow(0,x)}u_{\epsilon}(x^{\prime})\text{ and }\overline{F}(z)=\limsup_{(\epsilon,z^{\prime})\rightarrow(0,z)}F_{\epsilon}(z^{\prime}).
> $$ Then, $\underline{u}$ is an LSC viscosity supersolution of $$\overline{F}(\cdot,\underline{u}(\cdot),D\underline{u}(\cdot),D^{2}\underline{u}(\cdot))=0\text{ on }\mathcal{O}.$$

A similar result holds for USC subsolutions.

---

Intimately related to the passage to limits above is the so-called *Barles-Souganidis framework* [[BS91]](http://content.iospress.com/articles/asymptotic-analysis/asy4-3-05), which gives sufficient conditions for convergence of approximation schemes for equations of the form
$$F(\cdot,u(\cdot),Du(\cdot),D^2u(\cdot))=0 \text{ on } \mathcal{O}.$$
In particular, it establishes that any approximation scheme that is **monotone**, **stable**, and **consistent** with respect to a limiting equation that satisfies a *comparison principle* converges to its unique (bounded) viscosity solution. Note that the ideas in [[BS91]](http://content.iospress.com/articles/asymptotic-analysis/asy4-3-05) are very general, applying to any nonlinear second order elliptic equation.

*Remark*: [[BS91]](http://content.iospress.com/articles/asymptotic-analysis/asy4-3-05) use a stronger notion of comparison principle by accounting for the boundary conditions (sometimes referred to as a *strong comparison principle*). You can relax their result to more usual notions, but doing so requires that you check convergence at the boundary separately, roughly speaking.

Comment: @Kei: was my answer useful? I'm interested to see if this is what you were looking for. (just following up here)

Comment: Yes, thanks (and thank you very much for following up): the works you have pointed out look very interesting; I hope to get around to read them more carefully shortly. Do you also know some expositions of the result (or slightly sharper results) obtained by Crandall and Lions for first-order equations?

Comment: In terms of first-order equations, you can use the "passage to limits" result above and simply remove the $D^2$ terms. In terms of making the results sharper, you should be able to relax the above so that each $F_\epsilon$ is only USC instead of continuous (and LSC for the subsolution case). As for other results on approximation schemes, I recommend looking at the first paragraph of the Barles-Souganidis paper, in which the authors list approximation results for special cases (including Hamilton-Jacobi, if my memory serves me correctly).